# huge array in database, other suggestions?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doubtful that my approach to this is the best.
I somehow want to store an array in this format:

```
array( 
 year => array( 
         jan => array( day1 => 0, day2 => 0, and so on )
 );
```

this is my code to generate it:

```
$array = array(
);

for( $y = date( 'Y' ); $y <= date( 'Y' ); $y++ )
{
    $array[ $y ] = array();
    for( $m = 0; $m < 11; $m++ )
    {
        $array[ $y ][ substr( GetMonthName( $m ), 0, 3 ) ] = array();

        for( $d = 0; $d < cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, $m+1, $y ); $d++ )
            $array[ $y ][ substr( GetMonthName( $m ),  0, 3 ) ][ $d ] = 0;
    }
}
```

this generates quite a big array, and assuming it will add a new array every new yea, this will get very big.

I need to save it to an id in the database, so
id    data
1     ( huge array here )

what could I do instead?

Comment: what your table looks like ?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: right now my table is simply: id (connected to a user) and data(which i was going to store this array in). im using mysql

Comment: What speaks against serializing? http://php.net/serialize http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: Why store that data at all? You can easily compute it on demand, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider storing just the data you need, rather than the whole set of days in a year. For example:

```
id=101, data="2015-02-05"
id=101, data="2015-02-07"
```